# Grails not displaying SQL results in table, what am I missing?

Tags: sql, grails

I'm obviously missing something obvious here but I cant for the life of me work out what, I've setup a view to display a custom SQL query, but the screen is showing nothing, here's what I've got

Controller

```
def queueBreakdown(){
    String SQLQuery = "select state, count(test_exec_queue_id) as 'myCount' from dbo.test_exec_queue group by state"
    def dataSource
    def list = {
        def db = new Sql(dataSource) 
        def results = db.rows(SQLQuery)
        [results:results]
    }
}
```

If I run this manually I get a set of results back like so

```
state   myCount
1       1
test    2
test2   1
```

The queueBreakdown.gsp has the following...

```
<body>
    <a href="#list-testExecQueue" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="queueBreakdown-testExecQueue" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <h1><g:message code="Execution Queue Breakdown"  /></h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="Run State" title="Run State"/>
                    <g:sortableColumn property="Count" title="Count" />
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <g:each in="${results}" status="i" var="it">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                        <td>${it.state}</td>
                        <td>${it.myCount}</td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

But when I view the page I get nothing...  The table has been built but there are no lines  in it, what am I being thick about here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller code is really confusing, what is the action here ? queueBreakdown() or list() ? It seems like you have mixed up 2 actions together, and queueBreakdown() is not returning any model...

```
class SomeController {

    def dataSource

    def queueBreakdown() {
        String SQLQuery = "select state, count(test_exec_queue_id) as 'myCount' from         dbo.test_exec_queue group by state"
        def db = new Sql(dataSource) 
        def results = db.rows(SQLQuery)
        [results:results]
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha!  You've highlighted the issue, my controller was just written horribly badly wrong, and now quite obvious now I look at it and your corrected version.  This is down to copying and pasting on my part from multiple examples!  I've now altered my controller to match what you've posted and it now works great!  Cheers!  I'd vote you up if I could!